# Could you suggest me a pattern to log exceptions during java application lifecycle?

Tags: java, exception, logging, jsf-2

I want to use the simple `java.util.logging.*` package to log exceptions. Any suggestions, links, articles to do this in a basic but elegant way?
I should implement it in a Java EE application.

I was thinking to a singleton class... what do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following doesn't handle the case of logging all exceptions automatically but might get you closer.  At my current company we extended `Exception` with a `CompanyException` that supported a list of callbacks.  Something like:

```
public abstract class CompanyException extends Exception {
    private static final List<ExceptionCallback> callBacks =
            new ArrayList<ExceptionCallback>();

    public CompanyException(String message) {
        super(message);
        invokeCallbacks();
    }

    // register class to be called whenever exception is constructed
    public static void registerCallback(ExceptionCallback callback) {
        // we expect the registers to be done long before the first exception thrown
        List<ExceptionCallback> newCallbacks = new ArrayList<ExceptionCallback>();
        newCallBacks.addAll(callBacks);
        newCallbacks.add(callback);
        callBacks = newCallBacks;
    }

    private void invokeCallbacks() {
        for (ExceptionCallback callBack : callBacks) {
            try {
                callBack.exceptionConstructed(this);
            } catch (Throwable th) {
                // ignore it because we can't go recursive 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The callback was a simple interface:

```
public interface ExceptionCallback {
    public void exceptionConstructed(Exception exception);
}
```

Then all of our internal exceptions would throw these or rethrow/wrap external exceptions.  We then would register a logging class which could log exceptions using log4j or our internal logging mechanisms.  Obviously the exception could do the logging itself but we wanted the separation.  Our logger had a dedicated thread to do it in the background and send it to the central logging server. You need to be *very* careful about recursion if you throw while you are logging.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [Base 22's logging suggestions](https://wiki.base22.com/display/btg/Java+Logging+Standards+and+Guidelines), they're pretty basic but they cover a basic set of standard logging functionality.

I discourage the use of a Singleton, as with a modern logging framework you don't need them.